# Update RecyclerView in Android after selecting a Spinner item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecycleView` that gets data from a `MySQL` database where this `RecycleView` have one index.
Now I want to change the `RecylerView` item when I select an option from a `Spinner`.
How can I do this, please?

This is my adapter for `RecycleView`:

```
public class IncludedAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<IncludedAdapter.Holder> {

List<Included> list;
Context context;

public IncludedAdapter(List<Included> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.include_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {

    Included included = list.get(position);
    Glide.with(context).load(included.getIcon())

            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.boy)
                    .error(R.drawable.boy)
                    .centerCrop())
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.title.setText(included.getTitle());
    holder.desc.setText(included.getDescription());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title, desc;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_included);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_description);

        TypefaceHelper.typeface(title, MyApplication.getRegular());
        TypefaceHelper.typeface(desc, MyApplication.getRegular());
    }
}
}
```

and here is my activity code :

```
IncludedAdapter includedAdapter = new 
IncludedAdapter(subCategory.getInclude(), getActivity());
includedView.setAdapter(includedAdapter);
```

I tried a lot of solutions, but nothing worked.

Comment: Change an item? or Items?

Comment: use `OnItemSelectedListener`. Inside the `Spinner`'s `OnItemSelectedListener`, update the `RecyclerView`'s list however you want.

Answer (score 2):

The following can be used:

```
myAdapter.notifyItemChanged(Position);
```

Answer (score 0):

the type of objects that set for spinner and recycler we should be the same type.
you can create a model for both and when you select an option from a spinner the you should reload your  adapter like this:

```
IncludedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

use this class for your spinner to get the model:

```
public class SpinnerBaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<model> {

private Context context;
private List<model> values;

public SpinnerBaseAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List< model> values) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, (List< model>) values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.size();
}

@Override
public BasicClass getItem(int position) {
    return values.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView label = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    label.setText(values.get(position).getName());
    return label;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView label = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    label.setText(values.get(position).getName());

    return label;
   }
}
```

Hope to help.